# Converting date and time from shell script into python

Tags: python, shell

I am a beginner to python and I have this date and time code from shell script, and how do I make it into python, also how can I take date from last month till now

```
ToDay=`date "+%Y%m%d"`
CheckDATE=`date "+%Y-%m-%d" --date '1 day ago'`
NOWDATE=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
```

This is the python code

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
progToRun = 'python ' + ScriptDir + '/bin/panafapi.py -K ' + secretkey + ' --samples -j -r "{\\"query\\":{\\"operator\\":\\"all\\",\\"children\\":[{\\"field\\":\\"alias.ip_address\\",\\"operator\\":\\"contains\\",\\"value\\":\\"' + ResultFile + '\\"},{\\"operator\\":\\"any\\",\\"children\\":[{\\"field\\":\\"sample.update_date\\",\\"operator\\":\\"is in the range\\",\\"value\\":[\\"' + CheckDATE + 'T00:00:00\\",\\"' + NOWDATE + 'T23:59:59\\"]},{\\"field\\":\\"sample.create_date\\",\\"operator\\":\\"is in the range\\",\\"value\\":[\\"' + CheckDATE + 'T00:00:00\\",\\"' + NOWDATE + 'T23:59:59\\"]},{\\"operator\\":\\"any\\",\\"children\\":[{\\"field\\":\\"sample.malware\\",\\"operator\\":\\"is\\",\\"value\\":1},{\\"field\\":\\"sample.malware\\",\\"operator\\":\\"is\\",\\"value\\":4}]}]}]},\\"scope\\":\\"global\\",\\"size\\":1,\\"from\\":0,\\"sort\\":{\\"create_date\\":{\\"order\\":\\"desc\\"}}}" > ' + ResultDir + 'srciplist-' + ToDay + '.json'

ToDay = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
CheckDATE = datetime.strptime("2017-12-01", "%Y-%m-%d").date()
NOWDATE = datetime.now().date()
```

Error:

```
 progToRun = 'python ' + ScriptDir + '/bin/panafapi.py -K ' + secretkey + ' --samples -j -r "{\\"query\\":{\\"operator\\":\\"all\\",\\"children\\":[{\\"field\\":\\"alias.ip_address\\",\\"operator\\":\\"contains\\",\\"value\\":\\"' + ResultFile + '\\"},{\\"operator\\":\\"any\\",\\"children\\":[{\\"field\\":\\"sample.update_date\\",\\"operator\\":\\"is in the range\\",\\"value\\":[\\"' + CheckDATE + 'T00:00:00\\",\\"' + NOWDATE + 'T23:59:59\\"]},{\\"field\\":\\"sample.create_date\\",\\"operator\\":\\"is in the range\\",\\"value\\":[\\"' + CheckDATE + 'T00:00:00\\",\\"' + NOWDATE + 'T23:59:59\\"]},{\\"operator\\":\\"any\\",\\"children\\":[{\\"field\\":\\"sample.malware\\",\\"operator\\":\\"is\\",\\"value\\":1},{\\"field\\":\\"sample.malware\\",\\"operator\\":\\"is\\",\\"value\\":4}]}]}]},\\"scope\\":\\"global\\",\\"size\\":1,\\"from\\":0,\\"sort\\":{\\"create_date\\":{\\"order\\":\\"desc\\"}}}" > ' + ResultDir + 'srciplist-' + ToDay + '.json'
    TypeError: must be str, not datetime.date
```

Comment: What do you mean by fixing date and time? The only difference between today and nowdate is the formatting, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.date.today()
>>> yesterday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
>>> ToDay = today.strftime("%Y%m%d")
>>> CheckDATE = yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
>>> NOWDATE = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
>>> print ToDay
20180126
>>> print CheckDATE
2018-01-25
>>> print NOWDATE
2018-01-26
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert date using the following code:

```
CheckDATE = datetime.datetime.strptime("2017-12-01", "%Y-%m-%d").date()
ToDAY = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
CheckDATE = CheckDATE.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Adding date at the end only outputs the date part and omits time.
I hope this answers your question.

Edit: Updated based on additional information.

Comment: I added as you say, but I got error. I update the error above.

Comment: @KatarinaAlves Ah! I get your question now. It wasn't that clear earlier. You can use the code @glenn provided above. It should work for you application. You just need the output to be in a string format. `somedate.strftime()` will convert a date into string depending on the format you provide.